# Backtracking optimization in java

Tags: java, backtracking

I have an optimization problem, where Im trying to schedule some tasks called Assignatura.
My representation is, if I have N days, for each one I can have two tasks, and I represent it using a single array. So this is, in the positions that are even, this is the first task of the day, and in the odd, the second ones. So position 0,1 represents the first day, 2,3 the second one, etc.
The restriction is that I need to have at least one Assignatura each day, trying to minimize a certain quantity for each day, called getPerjudicats.

This is my code:

```
package backtracking;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SolucioCalendari {
    private int nDays, nAssignInADay;
    private boolean[] assignada;  // Track if an Assignatura has been assigned
    private Assignatura[] solucio;  // Current solution attempt
    private Assignatura[] millor_solucio;  // Best solution found so far
    private int millor_cost;  // Cost of the best solution
    private int assignades;  // Number of assigned Assignatura
    private int cost_actual;  // Current cost
    private Map<String, Integer> memoization;  // Cache for memoization

    public SolucioCalendari(int nDays, int nAssigInADay) {
        if (nDays * nAssigInADay < Assignatura.getPlaEstudis().length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El nombre d'assignatures es menor que nDays per nAssignInADay");
        }
        this.nDays = nDays;
        this.nAssignInADay = nAssigInADay;
        this.assignada = new boolean[Assignatura.getPlaEstudis().length];
        this.solucio = new Assignatura[nAssigInADay * nDays];
        this.millor_solucio = new Assignatura[nAssigInADay * nDays];
        this.millor_cost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        this.assignades = 0;
        this.cost_actual = 0;
        Arrays.fill(this.assignada, false);
    }

    public void start() {
        this.backMillorSolucio(0);
    }

    private void backMillorSolucio(int dia) {
        if (dia >= this.solucio.length) {
            if (assignades == Assignatura.getPlaEstudis().length && this.millor_cost > this.cost_actual) {
                this.millor_cost = this.cost_actual;
                this.millor_solucio = Arrays.copyOf(this.solucio, this.solucio.length);
            }
            return;
        }

        int remainingAssignatura = Assignatura.getPlaEstudis().length - assignades;
        int remainingSlots = this.solucio.length - dia;

        if (remainingAssignatura > remainingSlots) {
            return; //Cut off the recursion if impossible to assign all
        }

        //Try not assigning an Assignatura only if it does not leave insufficient slots
        if (remainingAssignatura < remainingSlots) {
            backMillorSolucio(dia + 1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Assignatura.getPlaEstudis().length; i++) {
            if (!assignada[i]) {
                this.solucio[dia] = Assignatura.getPlaEstudis()[i];
                assignada[i] = true;
                assignades++;
                int previousCost = this.cost_actual;

                boolean validAssignment = true;
                int perjudicatsCost = 0;

                if (dia % 2 == 1 && this.solucio[dia - 1] != null) {
                    int codi_anterior = (this.solucio[dia - 1].getCodi() / 1000) % 10;
                    int codi_actual = (this.solucio[dia].getCodi() / 1000) % 10;
                    if (codi_anterior != codi_actual) {
                        perjudicatsCost = Assignatura.getPerjudicats(
                            Assignatura.assignatures.indexOf(this.solucio[dia - 1]),
                            Assignatura.assignatures.indexOf(this.solucio[dia])
                        );
                        this.cost_actual += perjudicatsCost;
                    } else {
                        validAssignment = false;
                    }
                }

                if (validAssignment) {
                    backMillorSolucio(dia + 1);
                }

                this.cost_actual = previousCost;
                assignada[i] = false;
                assignades--;
                this.solucio[dia] = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getMillorResultat() {
        return this.millor_cost;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (Assignatura assignatura : millor_solucio) {
            s.append(assignatura == null ? "null " : assignatura.toString()).append(" ");
        }
        return s.toString().trim();
    }

    public void printaSolActual() {
        for (Assignatura assignatura : solucio) {
            System.out.print(assignatura + " - ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

However, for real cases, this is tacking too long. Are there any ways to further optimize this? I tried removing some permutations only creating solutions with a certain order in Assignatura, removing bad branches... But it is not enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understood your code completely, because it is not in English and there are things like `PlaEstudis` which you didn't explain. Your problem is a combinatorial optimization problem known as Constraint Programming, which is known to be NP-Hard, so the larger the input the longer it will take.

However, given your constraints (based only on your description, because the code is too cryptic), you can do something like this:

Assuming you have a number of days `d` and number of tasks `n`, where `2d >= n`.

1. Sort your tasks by their cost (Perjudicats) highest cost first.
2. Starting at the end of your array, allocate the first task (only) of each day to the next task from the list. So Day `d-1` Task 1 gets the most costly task, Day `d-2` Task 1 gets the next most costly etc. In the end of this step all days will have 1 task, with the most costly task at the last day.
3. With the remaining unallocated tasks `n-d`, allocate Task 2 of each day, but now starting from Day 0 moving forwards. In the end you will have some days at the end with only 1 task, but they will be the most costly tasks.

Unless I am missing something, you should have your costs distributed between all days.